# Bike difficult to pedal

Tags: chain, derailleur

I added a new rear wheel to my bike, and set the chain and spun it by hand so it spins properly. However it is very very difficult to pedal, requiring a lot of force. Also when I pedal, I hear a light grinding sound that I can't identify. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This usually means you've installed the rear wheel incorrectly.  But there are about a dozen different ways to screw it up, so you either need to take it to a bike shop or get a mechanically-inclined buddy to take a look at it.

Comment: Review everything you did to add the new rear wheel.  Undo some of your steps to isolate the problem.  Also, why did you change the rear wheel?  Is the replacement a known-good wheel?  Do you have the original wheel to swap back in for a test ?     The usual suspects are tyre-rub on the chainstay or mudguard or brake due to not seating the axle properly.  If the wheel spins freely but the pedals aren't, then you've got a problem in the chain/transmission area.

Comment: Also please have a browse through our tour in the Help menu, and search through the existing questions to see if anything is relevant.    Good work for attempting the repair on your own too!   Lastly, when you do identify the source of the noise/friction, take photos and add them to your question.  We can help more with more info.

Comment: We really need some photographs of your setup. It could be anything from your brakes to your chain to your frame.

Comment: spinning freely but can't pedal sounds like freewheel or chain jammed against the dropout

Comment: Derailleur tab in the S curve area?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, unless you provide further info.  Please use the EDIT link to expand your question with details and photos.   If your problem is resolved please add your own answer showing what the cause was, and how you resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a number of things. Any of the chainset components, hubs, brakes.

To narrow it down,

- Take the chain off the front chainring and pedal by hand, do you feel any resistance here? If so this could indicate a problem with the bottom bracket
- Spin the wheel off the ground by hand in a forward direction. Does it spin freely and continue spinning when you let go? If not this could indicate brakes or hub bearings
- If neither of the above are the problem then it's likely your gearing, and its probably best to take it to your local bike shop for repair.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, one more thing to look at is the tire width.  In my case, my road bike needs to run on 700x23 tires.  If I put on 700x25 tires, the sides start to rub the frame slightly when weight is on the bike even though it seems fine when I spin it on the bike stand.
Good luck.